# Grey objects in the material preview and the rendered mode look in Eevee render

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, error, gpu

In object mode, the objects look normal:

[image]

However, when in eevee, the material preview and the rendered mode look like this:

[image]

When I zoom or rotate I get this weird outline:

[image]

Please note that this is a brand new blender project in the images, but this same issue applies to all my projects. I have already tried setting back my driver but that hasn't worked. I've also tried downloading earlier versions of Blender, but somehow I get the same issue.

PC Specs (if that helps):
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19041) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500T CPU @ 2.10GHz (6 CPUs), ~2.1GHz
RAM: 8GB
DirectX Version: DirectX 12
Card name: Radeon RX 580 Series

Any help would be much appreciated.